# "Would you have a resume I can refer to?" or "Do you have a resume I can refer to?"

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

"Would you have a resume I can refer to?" or "Do you have a resume I can refer to?"

I want to ask someone for their resume, but I'm confused between would and do? Which one is correct and what's the difference between the two?

Comment: *Please send me your resume* avoids this problem, as well as the chance for them to simply reply *yes.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're both correct.  We sometimes use *would* to "soften" a request, command, or statement, or make it more polite.

For example,

> I want some water. : I would like some water.
> Hand me that book. : Would you hand me that book?

References:

- [The Many Uses of 'Would' in Everyday Speech, Part 1](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/the-many-uses-of-would-in-everyday-speech/4455867.html)
- [WOULD | Grammar | EnglishClub](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.htm)